# Is what I'm generating the UV coordinates?

Tags: opengl, glsl, webgl, fragment-shader

I don't usually use a flat surface in OpenGL, but recently I've been taking up on making After Effects plugins, and it has a template called Glator which passes a VBO which contains the UVs. However, I have learned by reading ShaderToy fragment shaders that by passing the resolution of the billboard to the fragment shader as a uniform, and doing this:

```
vec2 p = gl_FragCoord.st / resolution.xy
```

You can generate a value which is the UV coordinate of the fragment on the flat surface. Am I right?

Comment: AFAIK this is the UV of that fragment/pixel wrt to where it is on the screen (i.e. a screen space UV) but its not the UV of the surface which you are shading.

Comment: @borgleader is correct. If after effects is passing UVs / you should use those. `gl_FragCoord` is the screen coordinates

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. @gman